# export microsoft export autocorrect acl file to csv

Tags: csv, ms-word, autocorrect

Hello and thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I am a real newbie at all this.

I am trying to export my autocorrected words from Microsoft Word so I can use them in the chrome autocorrect extension '[spelling bee](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-bee/dfbnahffpakjbdlccohcoglcnafhgnhm?hl=en-US)  .' The chrome extension allows you to upload files of misspelled words and their autocorrection in csv format.

The problem I face is that my autocorrected list from microsoft word is an acl file. I have spent quite a while trying to figure out how to convert my acl file to a csv file with no success. I thought that I could just manually format the file myself When I open the acl file as a text file, but the formatting and spacing are so off, it would take forever to do it manually.

Is there a straight forward way to open the acl file in simple delimited format? There are many posts online about how to transfer acl files from one system to another, but I could not figure out how to simply convert the acl file into a csv or other appropriately delimited file.  If there is a thread out there that addresses this that I may have overlooked please let me know. Thanks again for your consideration.

**example of what my acl file looks like when I open it in text editor:** 

must of had
must have hadmyseflmyselfmyumynaivenaÔvenecassarilynecessarily necassary   necessaryneccessarilynecessarily
neccessary necessary
necesarilynecessarilynecesary   necessary
negotiaingnegotiatingnkowknownothignnothingnvernevernwenewnwonowobediantobedientocasionoccasion   occassionoccasionoccuredoccurred occurence
occurrence

Answer (score 0):

At this link there is a 18kb utitily which will backup your autocorrect to a word document, you can then copy that table into excel and make it into a .csv [Autocorrect utility](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/Customization/ExportAutocorrect.htm) . It's made for Word 97 and 2000, but I used it no problems with Word 2007 and 2010